# Property does not exist on type in GraphQL query result

Tags: typescript, graphql, graphql-codegen

In the React component I use a GraphQL query to fetch data:

```
const { data, error, loading } = useGetEmployeeQuery({
  variables: { id: "a34c0d11-f51d-4a9b-ac7fd-bfb7cbffa" }
});
```

On the data destructure

```
const { first_name } = data?.Employees_employees_by_pk;
```

type checking returns an error

```
Property 'first_name' does not exist on type 'Maybe<{ __typename?: "Employees_employees" | undefined; } & Pick<Employees_Employees, "id" | "first_name" | "last_name" | "email" | "avatar" | "started_at" | "created_at" | "updated_at">> | undefined'
```

Tried to assign a default `""` to `first_name`  which didn't help to eliminate the error.

The types are generated with graphql-codegen:

```
export type GetEmployeeQuery = (
  { __typename?: 'query_root' }
  & { Employees_employees_by_pk?: Maybe<(
    { __typename?: 'Employees_employees' }
    & Pick<Employees_Employees, 'id' | 'first_name' | 'last_name' | 'email' | 'avatar' | 'started_at' | 'created_at' | 'updated_at'>
  )> }
);
```

How do I get the query result to destructure nicely?

Comment: What happens when you inspect data in the debugger or with console logs? I think that the Maybe generic could extend Array

Comment: The received `data` contains the Object of `Employees_employees_by_pk` with all the expected props.

Comment: Just got the same problem. Any updates on this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should work

```
if( data && data.Employees_employees_by_pk ) {
  // no undefined here
  // safe access to 'base type' fields
  const { first_name } = data.Employees_employees_by_pk;
  // use first_name
}
```

... and it is logically (and by types) different to

```
const { first_name } = data?.Employees_employees_by_pk;
// possible access/destructure from undefined
```

Comment: This worked for me but I really dislike the syntax, especially when dealing with  nested values. Does anyone know of  a cleaner solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
const { data: { first_name } = {} } = useQuery<Data>(gql`...`);
```

So typescript will assume `data` is an empty object instead of undefined